# How to get the MailItems of a specific folder in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

My folder is called **`"Request Mailbox"`** in Outlook

How can I get a list of all **`mailitems`** in that folder

Comment: Where is that folder located relative to the top and/or Inbox folder?

Comment: It's a shared mailbox. It's 1 level down

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619 if you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

To get list of **`MailItems`**, you can simply do this

*MailItem list will be displayed as Email*

```
Option Explicit
Sub MailItems()
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Request Mailbox")

    Set olItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' Creat EMail
    With olItem
        For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
            Debug.Print olItem.Subject ' Print to immediate window
            .body = .body & olItem.Subject & vbCrLf ' Print to Email
            Debug.Print olItem.SenderName
            .body = .body & olItem.SenderName & vbCrLf
            Debug.Print olItem.ReceivedTime
            .body = .body & olItem.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Next ' vbCrLf = vb: Visual Basic Cr: Carriage Return Lf: LineFeed
        .Subject = "Mail Items" ' Subject
        .Display    ' Display Msg
    End With

End Sub
```

*For Shared Folder Try this*

```
Option Explicit
Sub ShareMailItems()
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim olShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olShareName = olNamespace.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com") '// Owner's email address
    Set olShareInbox = olNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder( _
                 olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders("Request Mailbox") '// FolderName

    Set olItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' Creat EMail
    With olItem
        For Each olItem In olShareInbox.Items
            Debug.Print olItem.Subject ' Print to immediate window
            .body = .body & olItem.Subject & vbCrLf ' Print to Email
            Debug.Print olItem.SenderName
            .body = .body & olItem.SenderName & vbCrLf
            Debug.Print olItem.ReceivedTime
            .body = .body & olItem.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Next ' vbCrLf = vb: Visual Basic Cr: Carriage Return Lf: LineFeed
        .Subject = "Mail Items" ' Subject
        .Display    ' Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For a delegate mailbox already open in Outlook, use `Application.Session.Folders.("TheDelegateMialboxName@YourCompany.com").Folders("TheFolderName")`

Comment: I guess I miss that part, If I am not mistaken there is no `"."` between `Folders.("The` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or you can expliiclty specify the Item function instead of relying on default property: `Application.Session.Folders.Item("TheDelegateMialboxName@YourCompany.com").Folders.Item("TheFolderName")`