# How to select only mailitems in a public folder in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I *automatically* select only mailitems in a certain public folder, say mypublicfolder, in the active explorer window of outlook?

Any ideas are welcome.

```
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = Application

Dim oItems As Object
If oItems.Class = olMail Then
    ' How to select only mailitems in a mypublicfolder in outlook explorer
End if

Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection
Set oSel = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
```

Comment: Do you want to **select** all mail items (why)? Or do you just want to iterate over mail items in a folder?

Comment: I would like to select mailitems such that oSel will have mailitems selected only. Please refer to the code.

Comment: Yes, but **why** do the items need to be selected? What do you plan to do afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

Application.Session.Folders.("TheDelegateMialboxName@YourCompany.com").Folders("TheFolderName")

For more information, please see the following link:

[How to get the MailItems of a specific folder in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008941/how-to-get-the-mailitems-of-a-specific-folder-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace curFldr with your own code to reference a public folder.

```
Private Sub SelectMailitems()

    Dim objExp As Explorer
    Dim curFldr As Folder
    Dim itm As Object

    Dim oItems As Object
    Dim oSel As Selection
    Dim i As Long

    Set objExp = ActiveExplorer

    ' Not valid in a conversation view
    objExp.ClearSelection

    Set curFldr = objExp.CurrentFolder
    Set oItems = curFldr.Items

    For Each itm In oItems
        If itm.Class = olmail Then
            objExp.AddToSelection itm
        End If
    Next

    Set oSel = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Debug.Print "oSel.count: " & oSel.count

    For i = 1 To oSel.count
        Debug.Print oSel(i).Subject
    Next

End Sub
```